# How to call modules.export route as an api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, module.exports

Greeting to everyone !! i have done something but i think i have done it wrong when its time for APIs

I have set my node js code for some routes like this

```
const admin_Controllers = require('./adminControllers/controllers')
// using the admin controller from the file 
admin_Controllers(app)
```

Like i am sending app as a parameter to the file and there i am coding like this

```
module.exports = (app) => {
    app.get('/viewall', (req, res) => {
        res.send("Hello i am stuck here")
    });
}
```

Now the issue is which path should i use to access this get request.

Comment: assuming app is express, you still need to initialize the server, when you do that you will specify the port... `app.listen(8080)` for example..m

Answer (score 3):

You should use the path which you have define for that specific middleware.

```
http://hostname:[port_number]/viewall
```

Comment: I have defined it Thank you for your response :)

Answer (score 2):

You can declare your function like this:

```
module.exports = {
    app(req,res){
        res.send("Hello i am stuck here")
    }
}
```

And you call using express.Router(), like:

```
const express = require('express');
const routes = express.Router();
const admin_Controllers = require('./adminControllers/controllers');
routes.get('/viewall', admin_Controllers.app);
```

Comment: In the code which you provide, there are some errors, calling `routes.get('/viewall', admin_Controllers.app);` this presume the module which you export has `app` property which isn't the case. And in that module precisly where will came the `app` function which you use?

Comment: @YvesKipondo The function can come from a Controller, the name of the function can be anything. This is how I work with NodeJS in backend. [Here](https://github.com/jonatandavi/nojs-application/tree/master/backend/src) you can se a example.